# OpenGL ES Shake Effect

Tags: android, opengl-es, shake

I'm creating a 2D game with OpenGL ES for Android.I want to perform a shake effect.

My idea is changing my camera's y coordinate but i'm not sure about algorithm.I have a position vector with x and y variables for my camera class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a duplicate of [Opengl Real world Camera Shake algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9125777/opengl-real-world-camera-shake-algorithm) . Essentially model the shaking after a Sin wave and modulate the amplitude depending on how much you want the camera to shake.

a really basic outline like below, you'll need to stop this when amplitude hits 0 among other things..

```
private float amplitude = 10.0f;
private float adjustAmplitudePerSecond = -1.0f;
private float timeElapsed = 0.0f;

public void shake(float deltaTime) {
    timeElapsed += deltaTime;
    amplitude += adjustAmplitudePerSecond * deltaTime;
    yourCamera.y += + Math.sin(timeElapsed);
}
```